Transactions in redis at high scale
I have to keep track of requests from users, each user's request can be counted only once.
I can only accept 10,000,000 users and I have requests coming at 50,000 qps. If a user makes a request that already succeeded, then we don't accept it
Can all of this be done in memory (redis cluster) to track users their IDs can be stored in a set, and keep a decremental counter to store remaining users count  Is it possible to check the count (above 0), and add user id to the set if not already present with a transaction that can handle 50K qps.
I came up with a solution of distributing counts in a batch of 1000 to the servers, they would make requests only if they have non zero count, when the count is 0 they ask for another batch.
This solution actually works but has a drawback that I could loose the counts if a server fails. And a server could stop recording requests before another one (not exactly fifo)
Both these drawbacks are acceptable but want to eliminate them to come up with a better solution.
